# Req for reopen: question after edit

Tags: discussion

[How do you politely deal with someone who avoids putting things in writing?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/6782/how-do-you-politely-deal-with-someone-who-avoids-putting-things-in-writing)

I have edited this question away from asking for a rewrite, to asking for how to insist on writing, and what to do if refused.

Please review and reopen if you see fit.